# Active X can't create Object

Tags: vb.net

For 2 weeks it's been like a hell to me. I have an application with crystal report, that I am running over my server. The problem is that I am running it from .exe extension. (Since I am not having code). 
What I have done :

1. Installed Sheredian.
2. Installed Crystal Run Time Engine .

Still when I run my module for printing a crystal report am facing `ACTIVE X CAN'T CREATE OBJECT`.

What should I do? I have registered crviewer.dll already. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give a little more details. What's the platform? 32 bits or 64? The problem could raise because of the platform mismatch: a 64 bit process can't intantiate a 32 bit activex class. Another problem would be non-present references. Check everything.

Comment: Show the code you are using to create the object

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it myself . In the path C:\Program Files\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.0\crystalreportviewers\ActiveXViewer I extracted avtiveXviewer.cab and replace it with my existing files in the same folder . Then I registered crviewer9.dll in cmd going to the same path usind cd and then using regsvr32 crviewer9.dll .Finally it is done .